# TextBox resets text when tabbing out ot other controls

Tags: winforms, .net-3.5, c#-3.0

I have a form with several controls. There a situtions where 'textBoxOtherRelationship' is disable and the text is set to string.empty. But when I then got to another control and tab out the data appears again,while the control remains disabled.

```
textBoxOtherRelationship.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", _binder, "RelationshipNotes"));


  private void ComboBoxRelationShipSelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if ((Constants.Relationship)comboBoxRelationShip.SelectedItem.DataValue == Constants.Relationship.Other)
            {
                textBoxOtherRelationship.Enabled = true;
                if (_formMode != ActionMode.ReadOnly)
                {
                    textBoxFirstName.BackColor = Color.White;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                textBoxOtherRelationship.Enabled = false;
                _model.RelationshipNotes = null;
                textBoxOtherRelationship.Text = string.Empty;
                if (_formMode != ActionMode.ReadOnly)
                {
                    textBoxFirstName.BackColor = Color.LightYellow;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm.. so I see this line here:

```
textBoxOtherRelationship.DataBindings.Add(
  new Binding("Text", _binder, "RelationshipNotes"));
```

which tells me that you've got binding set up between the `Text` property on the textBoxOtherRelationship and a property called "RelationshipNotes" on the datasource `_binder`.

Great.

So, I'm assuming that the two-way binding works just fine and that when you type something into the `textBoxOtherRelationship` and that control loses focus the underlying RelationshipNotes property is getting updated as well, right?

Now, looking at your code there, I don't think the underlying datasource is being updated when you set the `Text` property to `string.Empty` because that usually doesn't happen until the textbox loses focus and you've disabled the control.

If you add:

```
textBoxOtherRelationship.DataBindings[0].WriteValue();
```

after you set the value to `string.Empty` that string.Empty value will get stored back to the datasource because the databinding will know there is something to update.  Programmatically, it doesn't.

I see you have this line:

```
            textBoxOtherRelationship.Enabled = false;
            _model.RelationshipNotes = null; <<<----------------------
            textBoxOtherRelationship.Text = string.Empty;
```

Is `_model.RelationshipNotes` what is ultimately supposed to be bound to that textbox?

Answer (score 1):

The SelectedIndexChanged event doesn't commit the databindings until after the control loses focus, so the quick fix is to write the value first in your event:

```
private void ComboBoxRelationShipSelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (comboBoxRelationShip.DataBindings.Count > 0) {
    comboBoxRelationShip.DataBindings[0].WriteValue();

    if ((Constants.Relationship)comboBoxRelationShip.SelectedItem.DataValue ==
                                                 Constants.Relationship.Other) {
      textBoxOtherRelationship.Enabled = true;
      if (_formMode != ActionMode.ReadOnly) {
        textBoxFirstName.BackColor = Color.White;
      }
    } else {
      textBoxOtherRelationship.Enabled = false;
      _model.RelationshipNotes = null;
      textBoxOtherRelationship.Text = string.Empty;
      if (_formMode != ActionMode.ReadOnly) {
        textBoxFirstName.BackColor = Color.LightYellow;
      }
    }
  }
}
```